# Non local connections for django project server

Tags: django, pinax, django-manage.py

I ran the command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

It started the server up, but when I navigate to http://myipaddress:8000, my webbroswer doesnt connect. I also tried with my iphone safari brower and got the same thing.

I am using Mac OS X 10.6 and am connect to the the internet through my router.

Any suggestions on how to allow non-local connections so my friends can try out my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) check your firewall
2) make sure your router forwards connections on port 8000 to your computer

Comment: i logged into my router which is a Bell router. It has a setup page which lets me get traffic into my network and on to my computer. What service am I suppose to enable?

It has a drop down menu under the heading: servers. Should I enable a webserver? a DNS server?

Comment: this isn't really a question for SO anymore, but you probably need to enable a custom port (8000). it isn't one of the standard, typically named services (web=80, ssh=22 etc)